# Add a calendar to a JSF page

Tags: java, html, jsf

Can anyone help me how to add a pop up calendar in a JSF page.I need to add a calendar where the user will select the date and the selected date should be displayed in a text box. Can anyone help me to achieve the rich face calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the rich faces calendar in the following manner :-

```
<rich:calendar id="dtDOB" value="#{Bean.variableName}" styleClass="textBox"
     datePattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" required="true" 
    label="#{Something}" validator="Validator.Something" />
```

variableName will have setter and getter in your backing bean.The data type will be Date.
So when you actually select a date and submit the page your getter will contain the selected date.
Use
`getVariableName()` to retrieve selected value.

Your bean should look like this:-

```
@ManagedBean(name="Demo")  //Annotation.You can also define this entry in faces-config.xml
@RequestScoped    //Scope of the bean

public class TestDemo
{
private Date dtDateOfBirth;


public Date getDtDateOfBirth() {
        return dtDateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDtDateOfBirth(Date dtDateOfBirth) {
        this.dtDateOfBirth = dtDateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

Your modified rich:calendar should look something like this:-

```
<rich:calendar id="dtDOB" value="#{Demo.dtDateOfBirth}" styleClass="textBox"
     datePattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" required="true" 
    label="#{Something}" validator="Validator.Something" />
```

In case you don't want to use validation remove the validator and required attribute from rich:calendar tag

Comment: since I am new to spring web flow can You Help me where should i have to add the setter and getter in  backing bean.I don't have any idea rich calendar works

Comment: I am getting the following error:      /WEB-INF/flows/helloFlow/mainpage.xhtml: ELResolver cannot handle a null base Object with identifier 'Bean'

Comment: Bean in the answer is actually your manageBean.You need to declare the name of the manageBean, its scope in either faces-config.xml or you can use annotations.If you use latter you can straight away use ManageBean property on your bean. Your getter and setter will be in your bean.